# algorithm that does not turn back and selects only one solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl-algorithm

for example, have a 4x4 array of integers, I need to select one number from each row such that each selected number is in a different column and the sum of the selected numbers is as low as possible. The grid in question looks like this:

```
 1 2 3 1
 2 3 1 3
 2 2 1 2
 3 4 1 9
```

My program returns this answer:

```
1* 2 3 1
2 3* 1 3
2 2 1* 2
3 4 1  9*
```

but the best solution is:

```
 1 2 3 1*
 2 3 1* 3
 2* 2 1 2
 3 1* 1 9
```

What do I need to change in my function?

```
 struct r{
    bool moze;
    int quantity;
};
int ff,m1;
bool check(int n,r **tab, int k)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(tab[k][i].moze==true || tab[i][ff].moze==true)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool back(int n, r ** tab, int k){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (check(n,tab,k)){
            tab[k][i].moze=true;
            if (k==n-1)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    for(int c=0;c<n;c++)
                    {
                        if(tab[j][k].moze==true)
                            cout<<tab[j][i].quantity;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (back(n,tab,k+1))
                return true;
            else

                tab[k][i].moze=false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

how to fix my functions??

---

```
function mark(r, c, available):
    for each element in [r][]:
        mark available
    for each element in [][c]:
        mark available

function backtrack(table, temp, r, c, sum):
    check if sum is solution
    for row i in table:
        if temp[i][0] is not available go to next row
        for column j in table:
            if temp[i][j] is available:
                 mark(i, j, not available) 
                 backtrack(table, temp, i, j, sum+table[i][j])
                 mark(i, j, available again)
```

I have a pseudocode but I can not put it in my function,could someone help me, can not help himself

Comment: what you have to do is this: first think about the algorithm, second implement it. Not the other way around.

Comment: @Walter In all fairness, this is a very tricky algorithm (bipartite graph matching) so the "think about" part should be replaced by "read about".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since this is neither a simple nor a very common algorithm, please explain what it does, and provide some references to people who may be unfamiliar with the recursive bipartite matching.

Comment: Why is this question being posted serially? This is the 5th time I have see it in the last three days.

Comment: @Kunal must be some homework somewhere ...

Comment: Are you allowed to sort each row?

Comment: So, what's this, the 6th time you've asked basically this exact same question (I presume you also asked the others)? Doing this is very unlikely to get you answers. For one thing, many users see all / most of these questions and are instantly negative towards you for doing this. But the main reason is that, if you don't change much, the response is unlikely to change. Rather investigate the **reason** behind the lack of results from asking the question. And if you delete your question, if someone intended to help, they will be unable to do so as it is no longer there.

Comment: I cant see how this question is trick.. unless you want to complicate. One thing you can do is think this problem as a permutation problem, use `std::next_permutation` and, for each permutation, check the multiplication. Dont forget to keep the permutation with best solution.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  For what class?  What is the teaacher trying to teach you?  Programmnig or math, or both?

Comment: Please stop re-asking the same question using multiple accounts. If you do this again, we will be forced to take more serious action here. Instead, clarify or otherwise improve your original one.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just a small array, you can bruteforce (there is 4!=24 possibilities) and just take the best one

This function give you the minimum sum, it is easy to adapt the code if you also need the selected elements.
Note that INF is suppose to be big, and M is you given 4x4 array.

```
int aux(){
  std::vector<int> t(4);
  for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    t[i]=i;
  int mini=INF;

  do{
    int tmp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
      tmp+=M[i][t[i]];
    mini=std::min(mini, tmp);
  }while(std::next_permutation(t.begin(), t.end()));

  return mini;
}
```

Comment: bruteforce  i do, array 4x4 This is just an example,I am looking for solutions for backtracking for an array of size N

Comment: That was not clear from the question. Anyway, this is a minimum cost bipartite matching problem, you can use [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) which run in O(n^3). [Here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=hungarianAlgorithm) is a good reference for both, an easy but O(n^4) algorithm and the better O(n^3) algorithm.

Comment: I know that it can solve other algorithm, but I have to solve bactracking, my backtracking, selects only one solution,not go back,not looking for a better solution,I do not know what to change to make it do

Comment: Your function seems to run in O(n^2) solve the general case and is quite simple compare to the hungarian's algorithm. So most likely, it's just wrong and you cannot fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your function just returns the first result it finds.

You need to, instead of your 2 `return` statements, just record the best result as you go.

I won't write the code for you, as you would learn more by figuring it out yourself, but here's 2 hints to get you started:

- You may want to store the best result outside of the function, rather than passing it around.
- To store the best result, you'll have to store *all* the indices of the values you selected, not simply the resulting sum.

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: this helped but still not all I do not understand